# Swift - How get photo albums with all photos include iCloud Library?

Tags: ios, swift

I need get all photo albums from device. I use this code for fetch albums:

```
func fetchAlbums() {
       // Get all user albums 
        let userAlbumsOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        userAlbumsOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0")


        let userAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType.album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.any, options: userAlbumsOptions)

        userAlbums.enumerateObjects( {
            if let collection = $0.0 as? PHAssetCollection {
                print("album title: \(collection.localizedTitle)")

                let onlyImagesOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                onlyImagesOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %i", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

                if let result = PHAsset.fetchKeyAssets(in: collection, options: onlyImagesOptions) {
                    print("Images count: \(result.count)")
                    if result.count > 0  {
                        //Add album titie
                        self.albumsTitles.append(collection.localizedTitle!)
                        //Add album
                        self.albumsArray.append(result as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>)
                  }
                }
            }
        } )


    }
```

But i can't get all photos. All albums without photos from iCloud library, only local photos. 
I use Collection View for preview photo. Example my code for fetch photos from selected album:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell.self), 
                                  for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AlbumPhotoCollectionViewCell

                    //Array with albums
                    let asset = self.albumsArray[indexSelectedAlbum]

                    let album = asset[indexPath.item]

                    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()

                    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true


               PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: album as! PHAsset , 
                               targetSize: self.assetThumbnailSize,
                               contentMode: .aspectFill,
                               options: options, 
                               resultHandler: {(result, info)in
                                     if result != nil {

                                       cell.albumPhoto.image = result
                              }
                    })


                    return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change fetch and all working.
Old code:

```
if let result = PHAsset.fetchKeyAssets(in: collection, options: onlyImagesOptions){
 //Code
}
```

New code

```
let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: onlyImagesOptions)
```